# Angular Crossfade animation jumping at last step

Tags: angular

Can anyone help me out with this.
I am trying to create a crossfade component that does exactly that.
I have created a parent component **crossfade.component**:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

And it's code is this:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[rv-crossfade]',
  templateUrl: './crossfade.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crossfade.component.scss'],
})
export class CrossfadeComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(CrossfadeItemComponent)
  items: QueryList<CrossfadeItemComponent>;

  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.rotate();
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }

  private rotate(): void {
    let index = 0;
    const items = this.items.toArray();
    if (!items.length) return;

    const activeItems = this.items.filter((t) => {
      return t.active;
    });

    if (activeItems.length > 1) return;

    items[index].active = true;

    setInterval(() => {
      index = index === items.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;

      for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].active = i === index;
      }

      console.log(
        'index',
        index,
        items.filter((item: CrossfadeItemComponent) => item.active)
      );
    }, 4000);
  }
}
```

Then I have a **crossfade-item.component**:

```
<div *ngIf="active" [@crossFade]>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

with code:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[rv-crossfade-item]',
  templateUrl: './crossfade-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crossfade-item.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('crossFade', [
      transition('void => *', [
        style({
          opacity: 0,
          zIndex: -1,
        }),
        animate('0.8s ease-out'),
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(
          '0.8s ease-out',
          style({
            opacity: 1,
            zIndex: 10,
          })
        ),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class CrossfadeItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('@crossFade')
  @Input()
  public active: boolean;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

The idea is that I can have multiple items on a page and it will fade in and out between them when they become active. The html looks a bit like this:

```
<div class="relative" app-crossfade>
  <div app-crossfade-item>
    <div class="absolute red">
      <p>This is test 1<p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div app-crossfade-item>
    <div class="absolute orange">
      <p>This is test 2<p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div app-crossfade-item>
    <div class="absolute green">
      <p>This is test 3<p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div app-crossfade-item>
    <div class="absolute blue">
      <p>This is test 4<p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, after the last step, when it comes back in with the first item, it doesn't use the animation.

Here is a stackblitz showing the issue:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xsj83c

If you noticed test 4 swapping to test 1, there is no fade, it just swaps.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation should be like (I use :enter and :leave)

```
  animations: [
    trigger("crossFade", [
      transition(":enter", [
        style({ opacity: 0 }), //<--state before enter animation begins
        animate("1000ms", style({ opacity: 1 }))  //<--animate to get opacity 1 in 1000ms
      ]),
      transition(":leave", [
        animate("1000ms", style({ opacity: 0 }))])  //<--animate to get opacity 0 in 1000ms
    ])
  ]
```

See that in an animation, we can say from with state begin the animation. In your animation only animate, but you need defined the state initial when fade-in